# How to add multiple data objects using Array.fill in Angular

Tags: arrays, angularjs, typescript

I am developing some code using Angular. In my ts file, I have created an array as below

```
ArrayB= [
   { id: 1, src: 'url' },
   { id: 2, src: 'url' },
   { id: 3, src: 'url' },
   { id: 4, src: 'url' },
   { id: 5, src: 'url' }];
```

This is ArrayA

```
ArrayA = Array(5).fill(' ').map((index,_)=>({id:index,src:url}));
```

I have created grid in HTML file. I want put images (in URL) on each grid tiles.

```
<mat-grid-list cols="10">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let cell of ArrayA; let i = index">
      <div
        class="cell"
        cdkDropList
        [cdkDropListData]="cell"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
        [style.background]="i == indexOver ? 'yellowgreen' : 'yellowgreen'"
        (mouseover)="this.indexOver = i"
        (mouseout)="indexOver = -1" >

        <div cdkDrag>
          <img
            *ngIf="cell.src"
            [src]="cell.src"
            width="100%"/>

          <span *ngIf="!cell.src"></span>

          <div *cdkDragPlaceholder></div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
```

So how can I put multiple data objects to ArrayA like ArrayB and assign images to each grid tile.

Comment: What do you expect in ArrayA? Please give sample expected output. You haven't shown what is the value of `url`.

Comment: edited the code